# JSP String array comparison

Tags: java, arrays, string, jsp

This may be a repeat question but I couldnt find any working answer.

So in my jsp, I am trying to compare two arrays, one containing answers selected by users in array c[] and right answersin cAns[] which I obtain from session variables.

I am trying to compare these two arrays but it always returns wrong ans despite of selecting the right one.

```
        String c[]=new String[Ques_low];
        String cAns[]=new String[Ques_low];
        for(int i=0;i<Ques_low;i++)
        {
            c[i]=(String)request.getParameter(""+i);
            cAns[i]=(String)session.getAttribute(""+i);
            if(c[i].equals(cAns[i])) {
                out.println("Right Ans");           
            } else {
               out.println("Wrong Ans");
            }
        }
```

Regards

Comment: No curly braces for in your if statement....

Comment: @James Massey.. No change.. I've added the braces.. Thank you

Comment: So it looks like the code in your question?

Comment: @ArpitaMaddali try to print `(String)request.getParameter(""+i);` and `(String)session.getAttribute(""+i);` and check whether they are having values??

Comment: @Prashant.. Got it! Error lies there.. getParameter was appending a space at the end.. Thanks a ton James and Prashant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        String c[] = new String[Ques_low];
        String cAns[] = new String[Ques_low];

        for (int i = 0; i < Ques_low; i++) {
            c[i] = (String) request.getParameter("" + i);
            cAns[i] = (String) session.getAttribute("" + i);
            out.println(Arrays.asList(c).containsAll(Arrays.asList(cAns)));
        }
```